# Query suggestion based on list for PnP

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, pnp

My site is in SharePoint 365.  I have a list of "locations".  I need to understand the steps to get my PnP Search bar suggest the items from the list.  I have created a site column and managed property.  Do I need to create a custom query provider?

Comment: how can we display the search bar from PnP search WP , this does not work ! no autocomplete suggested by the last version of these WP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the PnP Search bar suggest items from your "locations" list in SharePoint Online, you can follow these general steps:

Create a Site Column: Create a site column of type "Single line of text" or "Managed Metadata" to store the location names. This column will be used to populate the suggestions in the search bar.

Add the Site Column to the "locations" List: Add the site column to the "locations" list, allowing you to store the location names for each item.

Create a Managed Property: Create a managed property in the SharePoint Search Schema to map to the site column you created. Ensure that the managed property is set to be queryable and searchable.

Perform a Full Crawl: Run a full crawl of your SharePoint Online content to ensure that the new managed property is indexed and available for search.

Configure PnP Search Web Part: Use the PnP Search Web Part to display the search bar on your page. Configure the web part to use the created managed property as a suggestion source.

Custom Query Provider (Optional): If you want to further customize the search behavior or refine the search results, you can create a custom query provider using the SharePoint Search Query API. However, for basic suggestion functionality, a custom query provider may not be necessary.

Comment: We ended up using the search functionality of the PnP Filter.  As you type, it offers suggestions based on the list.    This met the requirement quite well.